# Javascript problema em converter value para int

Tags: javascript

Preciso de 2 funções que apanham o valor de um `input` e mandem para outro `input` esse valor +2, já tinha feito esta pergunta aqui mas foi para +3 e consegui a solução, no entanto fiz outra função com outro nome e outros campos, e o resultado foi `NaN`. Aqui esta o código de +3 que funciona:

```
function tenta() {
    if(document.getElementById('ciclo').value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById('ciclo2').value = "2013"; //placeholder
         document.getElementById('ciclo2').style.color = "#bfbfbf";
    }else
    {
        document.getElementById('ciclo2').style.color = "black";
        var x = document.getElementById('ciclo').value;
        document.getElementById('ciclo2').value = parseFloat(x) + 3;
    }
}
```

e a função igual, mas retorna `NaN`:

```
    function numeros2()
        {
            if(document.getElementById('ciclo3').value == "")
            {
               document.getElementById('ciclo4').value = "2013"; //placeholder;
                 document.getElementById('ciclo4').style.color = "#bfbfbf";
            }else
            {
                document.getElementById('ciclo4').style.color = "black";
                var xy = parseInt(document.getElementById('ciclo4').value);
                document.getElementById('ciclo4').value = xy + 2;
            }
        }
```

Já tentei o `parseFloat`, mas também não funciona.

Comment: Valores vazios são NaN mesmo. Acho que seu problema está nos if .. else, não tem muito a ver com o valor. Você testa o ciclo, mas muda o ciclo2. Depois testa o ciclo3, mas aplica no ciclo4. É isso mesmo? Ponha um [mcve] no JS Fiddle e mande o link pra gente testar.

Comment: É o mesmo HTML da outra pergunta?

Comment: Sim Sergio e o mesmo `HTML`. Os inputs têm um `onkeyup`.

Comment: Ola, fiz um jsfiddle mas não consegui replicar o seu constrangimento. http://jsfiddle.net/q6jGr/196/ Pode criar para então ser possivel ajudar.

Comment: é exatamente isso Tiago Gomes, mas em vez de ser necessário clicar, é feito um event `onkeyup`. mas o erro é mesmo esse, num funciona no outro não.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que `parseInt("")` dá `NaN`, ou seja, quando a string está vazia o `parseInt` dá isso, que quer dizer *"**N**ot **a** **N**umber"* ("Não é um número").

Tens de fazer assim: `var xy = parseInt(ciclo3.value || 0, 10);`. Dessa maneira ele escolhe o zero, caso o `value` fôr uma string vazia. Deves ter em conta que string vazia valida como "false" quanto convertida em Boolean.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kcqvfq14/1/

Comment: Sérgio, o output desse jsfiddle não é o pretendido, o que queria é que mete-se por exemplo 2010 num campo e no campo que vai receber a função é que adicione mais 2, ou seja o value do `input` será 2012. Como sou novo no javascript não percebo bem esse "0,10".

Comment: @programmer2016 editei. Tinha corrigido o problema com o parseInt mas era preciso também corrigir para ciclo3.

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que o `document.getElementById("ciclo").value` não esteja retornando uma String. Nem todos os objetos do DOM possuem a propriedade "value".

Verifique qual objeto está sendo retornado nesta porção do código e utilize a forma adequada para obter o dado que precisa.

Se você esclarecer qual é o Node retornado de `document.getElementById("ciclo")` e HTML ficará mais fácil postar uma resposta mais específica para seu problema.